# Django: How to refresh table after filtering without refreshing the whole page?

Tags: javascript, python, django, python-3.x

The root of the issue is how to refresh the filtered table dynamically, without refreshing the whole page.

I am almost novice in **python/html/css**, so please make some comments like for a newbie [Thanks].
After some research on StackOverFlow, I found that it could be made with **js**, but I have almost no experience with js and I don't know how to use it in **Django**.

Is there any possibility using only Django tools? And how efficient it would be?
Maybe you can provide some examples of resolving the issue.

Here is the model:

```
class Player(models.Model):
    last_name = models.CharField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name="прізвище"
    )
    first_name = models.CharField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        max_length=255,
        verbose_name="ім'я"
    )
    city = models.ForeignKey(
        City,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="місто"
    )
    rating = models.PositiveIntegerField(
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="рейтинг"
    )
    rank = models.ForeignKey(
        Rank,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        verbose_name="ранг"
    )
    local_rank = models.ForeignKey(
        LocalRank,
        null=True,
        blank=True,
        on_delete=models.SET_NULL,
        verbose_name="розряд"
    )

def __str__(self):
    if self.last_name and self.first_name:
        return self.last_name + ' ' + self.first_name
    elif self.egd_last_name and self.egd_first_name:
        return self.egd_last_name + ' ' + self.egd_first_name
    else:
        return self.id
```

I am using **django-tables2** to render the table:

```
class PlayerTable(tables.Table):
    full_name = tables.LinkColumn(
        accessor="__str__",
        verbose_name="Прізвище та ім'я",
        order_by="last_name",
        viewname='UGD:player_info',
        empty_values=(),
        args=[A('pk')]
    )
    local_rank = tables.Column(
        accessor="local_rank.abbreviate",
        order_by="id"
    )
    ufgo_member = tables.BooleanColumn(
        verbose_name="Член УФГО"
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = (
            'id',
            'full_name',
            'city',
            'rating',
            'rank',
            'local_rank',
            'ufgo_member'
        )
        attrs = {'class': 'main'}
```

I am using **django-filter** to make a filter form:

```
    class PlayersFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    last_name = django_filters.CharFilter(
        lookup_expr='contains',
        label="Прізвище"
    )
    first_name = django_filters.CharFilter(
        lookup_expr='contains',
        label="Ім'я"
    )
    city = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(
        choices=[(city.id, city.name) for city in City.objects.all()],
        empty_label="--Не обрано--",
        label="Місто"
    )
    ufgo_member = django_filters.ChoiceFilter(
        choices=[
            (False, 'Ні'),
            (True, 'Так')
        ],
        name="ufgo_member",
        label="Член УФГО",
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Player
        fields = (
            'last_name',
            'first_name'
        )
```

The following is the issue - view / template.

I am using **SingleTableMixin** and **FilterView** in my view to take care of table and filter:

```
class RatingListView(SingleTableMixin, FilterView):
    table_class = PlayerTable
    table_pagination = False
    template_name = 'UGD/rating_list.html'
    filterset_class = PlayersFilter
```

Here I have an idea to divide the view on several parts, but I still don't know how to do it.
Maybe you have some suggestions to make it better?

My template:

```
<body>
    <div class="filter">
        <form id="filter_submit" class="filter">
            {% block content %}
                <div class="filter">
                    <table class="filter">
                        {{ filter.form.as_table }}
                    </table>
                    <button id="filter_submit_button" type="submit">OK</button>
                </div>
            {% endblock %}
        </form>
    </div>
    <div>
        {% render_table table %}
    </div>
</body>
```

I think I should add some script, but I don't know how to use **js** yet.

**The issue: after chosing filters and pressing OK, the whole page is refreshed with new data**

And I want that only table was refreshed.

Please, give me a hint on how to do it.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Ajax queries/requests

Comment: Yep, I know, but I need an example with using django-tables/filters

Comment: Are you using checkboxes as filters? Buttons? Or what? You can help us by clarifying that.

Comment: @AlanAvalos,I use django-filters module: there are two text-search-fields and two dropdowns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the django-filter documentation (https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/index.html), this app does the filtering in the back-end. I didn't see any javascript code executed to do this and it handles the filtering logic in the views. So that's why the app needs to refresh the page to show you the filtered table as a result.

I'm going to recommend you to implement the filtering functionality with javascript. You need to identify the elements of the table that you want to filter, the trigger elements (dropdowns and search boxes, as in django-filter) and link both of them to make modifications to the DOM. This way, you can have a dynamic table filter.

These couple of links can get you started with this:

http://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_filter_table.asp

http://codepen.io/abocati/pen/vdKce [1]

[1]
JS

```
(function(document) {
'use strict';

var LightTableFilter = (function(Arr) {

    var _input;
var _select;

    function _onInputEvent(e) {
        _input = e.target;
        var tables = document.getElementsByClassName(_input.getAttribute('data-table'));
        Arr.forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
            Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
                Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filter);
            });
        });
    }

    function _onSelectEvent(e) {
        _select = e.target;
        var tables = document.getElementsByClassName(_select.getAttribute('data-table'));
        Arr.forEach.call(tables, function(table) {
            Arr.forEach.call(table.tBodies, function(tbody) {
                Arr.forEach.call(tbody.rows, _filterSelect);
            });
        });
    }

    function _filter(row) {

        var text = row.textContent.toLowerCase(), val = _input.value.toLowerCase();
        row.style.display = text.indexOf(val) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';

    }

    function _filterSelect(row) {

        var text_select = row.textContent.toLowerCase(), val_select = _select.options[_select.selectedIndex].value.toLowerCase();
        row.style.display = text_select.indexOf(val_select) === -1 ? 'none' : 'table-row';

    }

    return {
        init: function() {
            var inputs = document.getElementsByClassName('light-table-filter');
            var selects = document.getElementsByClassName('select-table-filter');
            Arr.forEach.call(inputs, function(input) {
                input.oninput = _onInputEvent;
            });
            Arr.forEach.call(selects, function(select) {
     select.onchange  = _onSelectEvent;
            });
        }
    };
})(Array.prototype);

document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
    if (document.readyState === 'complete') {
        LightTableFilter.init();
    }
});

})(document);
```

Comment: Thank you, I will try to understand that.